# How to update local module?

Tags: npm

package.json

```js
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "my-local": "file:../local/my-local",
    // other dependencies
  },
  // ...
```

I tried `npm install`, doesn't work. `npm update my-local` also doesn't seem to work, possibly because I don't iterate version for each small change I make? (early development stage)

---

Only reliable way I've found is to `npm uninstall my-local` and reinstall but it's very annoying.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another tool for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates. Install that with:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Then:

```
ncu -u
npm install
```

the install is necessary as `ncu` just updates the package.json, not install anything.